# Copy all members of a class to current object

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, copy-constructor, shallow-copy

Let's assume I have a base class called `BaseClass` and  an object called `Foo` that inherited from `BaseClass`. Can I copy all members of a `BaseClass` instance to current object being created instead of do it manually?

```
class BaseClass
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    const char *e;
};

class Foo : BaseClass
{
public:

    Foo(BaseClass* bc, int x, const char *value)
    {
        // copy bc->a to this->a and bc->b to this->b 
        // and so on with all the members of BaseClass class
        this->x = x;
        this->s = value;
    }

    int x;
    const char *s;
};
```

Can I do this?
Another possible solution with `memcpy()`, not sure if it's ugly or can't work but assuming the members allocated in order, with `BaseClass` first, ie, this class became something like in memory:

```
   struct
    {
        // members of BaseClass
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        const char *e;
        // members of Foo
        int x;
        const char *s;
    };
```

Something like this in `Foo` constructor:

```
memcpy(this, &bc, sizeof(*bc));
```

Should copy all members of `bc` into current object, right? is this dangerouos?

Btw, I'm doing this in a C-style. I don't do much C++. C++-way to do it are very welcome.

Comment: Be aware of object-slicing. Copying and polymorphism don't always play nice, because which copy constructor is called is determined at compile-time. A common solution is to create a virtual clone method, which each derived class overrides as necessary to return the right type of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your declaration of the Foo constructor to include a constructor for the base class:

```
Foo(BaseClass* bc, int x, const char *value): BaseClass(*bc)
```

Comment: `Foo f1, f2; BaseClass& b1 = f1, b2 = f2; b1 = b2;` whoops!